# How to create a loop for sum calculations which then are inserted into a new row?

Tags: r, loops, sum

I have tried to find a solution via similar topics, but haven't found anything suitable. This may be due to the search terms I have used. If I have missed something, please accept my apologies.

Here is a excerpt of my data `UN_` (the provided sample should be sufficient):

```
 country year sector       UN 
      AT 1990      1 1.407555  
      AT 1990      2 1.037137  
      AT 1990      3 4.769618  
      AT 1990      4 2.455139  
      AT 1990      5 2.238618  
      AT 1990  Total 7.869005  
      AT 1991      1 1.484667  
      AT 1991      2 1.001578  
      AT 1991      3 4.625927  
      AT 1991      4 2.515453 
      AT 1991      5 2.702081 
      AT 1991  Total 8.249567 
      ....
      BE 1994      1 3.008115  
      BE 1994      2 1.550344  
      BE 1994      3 1.080667  
      BE 1994      4 1.768645  
      BE 1994      5 7.208295  
      BE 1994  Total 1.526016  
      BE 1995      1 2.958820  
      BE 1995      2 1.571759 
      BE 1995      3 1.116049  
      BE 1995      4 1.888952
      BE 1995      5 7.654881  
      BE 1995  Total 1.547446 
      ....
```

What I want to do is, to add another row with `UN_$sector = Residual`. The value of residual will be `(UN_$sector = Total) - (the sum of column UN for the sectors c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))` for a given year AND country.

This is how it should look like:

```
 country year      sector       UN 
      AT 1990           1 1.407555  
      AT 1990           2 1.037137  
      AT 1990           3 4.769618  
      AT 1990           4 2.455139  
      AT 1990           5 2.238618  
----> AT 1990    Residual TO BE CALCULATED
      AT 1990       Total 7.869005
```

As I don't want to write many, many lines of code I'm looking for a way to automate this. I was told about loops, but can't really follow the concept at the moment.

Thank you very much for any type of help!!

Best,

Constantin

PS: (for Parfait)

```
   country year sector        UN ETS
   UK      2012      1 190336512  NA
   UK      2012      2  18107910  NA
   UK      2012      3   8333564  NA
   UK      2012      4  11269017  NA
   UK      2012      5   2504751  NA
   UK      2012  Total 580957306  NA
   UK      2013      1 177882200  NA
   UK      2013      2  20353347  NA
   UK      2013      3   8838575  NA
   UK      2013      4  11051398  NA
   UK      2013      5   2684909  NA
   UK      2013  Total 566322778  NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider calculating residual first and then stack it with other pieces of data:

```
# CALCULATE RESIDUALS BY MERGED COLUMNS
agg <- within(merge(aggregate(UN ~ country + year, data = subset(df, sector!='Total'), sum),
                    aggregate(UN ~ country + year, data = subset(df, sector=='Total'), sum),
                    by=c("country", "year")),
             {UN <- UN.y - UN.x
              sector = 'Residual'})

# ROW BIND DIFFERENT PIECES
final_df <- rbind(subset(df, sector!='Total'),
                  agg[c("country", "year", "sector", "UN")],
                  subset(df, sector=='Total'))

# ORDER ROWS AND RESET ROWNAMES
final_df <- with(final_df, final_df[order(country, year, as.character(sector)),])
row.names(final_df) <- NULL
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/WBRYB18635)

```
final_df
#    country year   sector         UN
# 1       AT 1990        1   1.407555
# 2       AT 1990        2   1.037137
# 3       AT 1990        3   4.769618
# 4       AT 1990        4   2.455139
# 5       AT 1990        5   2.238618
# 6       AT 1990 Residual  -4.039062
# 7       AT 1990    Total   7.869005
# 8       AT 1991        1   1.484667
# 9       AT 1991        2   1.001578
# 10      AT 1991        3   4.625927
# 11      AT 1991        4   2.515453
# 12      AT 1991        5   2.702081
# 13      AT 1991 Residual  -4.080139
# 14      AT 1991    Total   8.249567
# 15      BE 1994        1   3.008115
# 16      BE 1994        2   1.550344
# 17      BE 1994        3   1.080667
# 18      BE 1994        4   1.768645
# 19      BE 1994        5   7.208295
# 20      BE 1994 Residual -13.090050
# 21      BE 1994    Total   1.526016
# 22      BE 1995        1   2.958820
# 23      BE 1995        2   1.571759
# 24      BE 1995        3   1.116049
# 25      BE 1995        4   1.888952
# 26      BE 1995        5   7.654881
# 27      BE 1995 Residual -13.643015
# 28      BE 1995    Total   1.547446
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait. When I run your code, it multiplies my values by 100 (moves comma and figures have three places more).

Comment: Hmmmm...your data must differ from posted sample as this solution with a linked demo shows output renders as you desire without any 100 multiplication. Please `dput` a sample of few rows from actual data.

Comment: Just added some lines of data. The last column was added just now, but I added it to your code and there was not issue with that. I'm just confused about the multiplication.

Comment: I have run the same thing again and this time it didn't do the multiplication. So, the error was elsewhere. Thank you for your excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways you can do this. What I may recommend is to take advantage of the `tidyverse` suite of packages which includes `dplyr`.

Without getting too far into what `dplyr` and `tidyverse` can achieve, we can talk about the power of dplyr's inline commands `group_by(...)`, `summarise(...)`, `arrange(...)` and `bind_rows(...)` functions. Also, there are tons of great tutorials, cheat sheets, and documentation on all `tidyverse` packages.

Although it is less and less relevant these days, we generally want to avoid for loops in R. Therefore, we will create a new data frame which contains all of the Residual values then bring it back into your original data frame.

**Step 1: Calculating all residual values**

We want to calculate the sum of UN values, grouped by `country` and `year`. We can achieve this by this value

`res_UN = UN_ %>% group_by(country, year) %>% summarise(UN = sum(UN, na.rm = T))`

**Step 2: Add sector column to res_UN with value 'residual'**

This should yield a data frame which contains `country`, `year`, and `UN`, we now need to add a column `sector` which the value 'Residual' to satisfy your specifications.

`res_UN$sector = 'Residual'`

**Step 3 : Add res_UN back to UN_ and order accordingly**

`res_UN` and `UN_` now have the same columns and they can now be added back together.

`UN_ = bind_rows(UN_, res_UN) %>% arrange(country, year, sector)`

Piecing this all together, should answer your question and can be achieved in a couple lines!

**TLDR:**

```
res_UN = UN_ %>% group_by(country, year) %>% summarise(UN = sum(UN, na.rm = T))`
res_UN$sector = 'Residual'
UN_ = bind_rows(UN_, res_UN) %>% arrange(country, year, sector)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts and very clear explanation! I just tried to code, but getting an error message `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :  Column `UN` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 6`

Comment: hey Constantin, I completely forgot to add the  sum command! I fixed it. 

`summarise(UN = sum(UN, na.rm = T))` 

By the way, na.rm can be true or false depending on what your specifications.

Comment: Thanks again. Code is running, but it is not calculating the residuals, but summing up sectors 1 to 6 and Total. It should do Total - Sectors 1 to 6